# How to login without password in Parse Server?

Tags: parse-platform

I am developing an app using Parse-Server with an own way to authenticate. How do I log user in without knowing the password?

From previous answers, I found this `Parse.User.become(<token>)`, but unable to fetch the token anywhere. I have this in cloud code, but it doesn't seem to work `token` is `undefined`. Probably because there's no session in the user, because the user isn't logged in at all (session is revocable).

```
function login(userId,callback) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.get(userId, {useMasterKey : true}).then(function(user){
        if (user) {
            console.log(user)
            var token = user.getSessionToken();
            console.log('Token ' + token);
            if (typeof callback === "function") callback({token:token});            
        }
    },function(error){
        if (typeof callback === "function") callback({error:error});
    })
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think I'm late but this would be helping someone on day...
Here's my workaround that doesn't need to change password :

```
async impersonate(installationID: string, username: string): Promise<string> {

// Retreiving user
const user = await new Parse.Query<Parse.User>('_User').equalTo('username', username).first({ useMasterKey: true });

// Retreiving existing session
const session = await new Parse.Query(Parse.Session)
  .equalTo('user', user)
  .equalTo('installationId', installationID)
  .first({useMasterKey: true});

if (session) {
  // Session already exist, using it !
  return session.get('sessionToken');
} else {

  // Manually create session (without using Parse.Session because of it's update restrictions)
  let session2 = new Parse.Object('_Session', {
    'user': user,
    'installationId': installationID,
    'sessionToken': `r:${uuidv4()}`
  });
  session2 = await session2.save(undefined, {useMasterKey: true});
  return session2.get('sessionToken') as string;
}}
```

Now you can juste logIn using "User.become()" with the token returned by the code above.
Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this. Probably not ideal but at least it works.

So we will generate a random password and login with that password in Cloud code. We then have the session token from `user.getSessionToken();` then pass it to frontend and use `Parse.User.become()` to login. Something like this:

```
function login(userId,callback) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.get(userId, {useMasterKey : true})
    .then(function(user){
        if (user) {
            console.log(user)
            var randomPassword = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
            user.setPassword(randomPassword);
            user.save(null,{useMasterKey:true}).then(function(user){
                Parse.User.logIn(user.get("username"),randomPassword)
                .then(function(user){
                    var token = user.getSessionToken();
                    console.log('Token ' + token);
                    if (typeof callback === "function") callback({token:token});                       
                }, function(error) {
                    if (typeof callback === "function") callback({error:error});
                })
            }, function(error){
                if (typeof callback === "function") callback({error:error});
            })

        }
    },function(error){
        if (typeof callback === "function") callback({error:error});
    })
}
```

Comment: Haha! What if they need to log in again?

Comment: @InfinitePrime they can log in again too.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the ```user.save``` part after setting ```random``` password on the fly.

Comment: If you change the password, then the user cant log in again